# System update went wrong 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, system-settings, reinstall

When 16.04 installation started, update gave me three options to choose between displays, I don't have a clew what I have chosen. It might be a problem to start with

When new system installation was finished, instead of opening laptop start screen, it opens terminal. It took me a time to find out how to start system, but it works with command startx

When home screen is opened, it is too big, and I do not see left line with commands, and don't see top line where settings, wifi, etc.

Most of devices on my laptop don't work, like wifi, bluetooth, etc. Computer can not find devices.

So, please, anyone has suggestions what should I do? Reinstall 16.04? Or repair it? What kind of display should I choose? Can I change display version now (before starting repair or reinstallation) through terminal?

If anyone can give me answers and instruction I'll gladly appeciate it.
Thanks,

Liliks

Comment: You've described a circumstance where your desktop manager isn't starting.  Star out by address this issue.  Manually try to start it by running `sudo systemctl start lightdm`.  Give us that what happens when you try to start it.

Comment: It is trying to star but without success. Canging from dark screen to lighter one (coulor change before to start Ubuntu, shows the mouse arrow for a sec and bac to black screen and new try again and again, for about 10-15 min now.

Comment: restarted laptop, bac to what was before. putting same command to terminal now, and getting same thing happening

Comment: Just once is sufficient to see what happens.  From your description, you are having problems with your graphics adapter.  Will you append the output of `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12` to your question?